# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'. Where did I go wrong in my code?

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am trying to generate the reverse complement for DNA sequences of multiple file types with a python script. Here is what I have written so far

```
import gzip
import re

############## Reverse Complement Function #################################
def rev_comp(dna):
    dna_upper = dna.upper() #Ensures all input is capitalized
    dna_rev = dna_upper[::-1] #Reverses the string

    conversion = {'A':'T','C':'G','G':'C','T':'A','Y':'R','R':'Y',\
       'S':'S','W':'W','K':'M','M':'K','B':'V','V':'B',\
       'D':'H','H':'D','N':'N','-':'-'}

    rev_comp = ''
    rc = open("Rev_Comp.fasta", 'w')
    for i in dna_rev:
        rev_comp += conversion[i]
        rc.write(str(rev_comp))
    print("Reverse complement file Rev_Comp.fasta written to directory")    

x = input("Enter filename (with extension) of the DNA sequence: ")

if x.endswith(".gz"):    #Condition for gzip files
    with gzip.open(x, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
        new_file = open("unzipped.fasta", 'w')
        new_file.write(str(file_content))
        print("unzipped.fasta written to directory")

xread = x.readlines()
fast = ''

if x.endswith(".fasta"):   #condition for fasta files
    for i in xread:
        if not i.startswith('>'):
            fast = fast + i.strip('\n')

if x.endswith(".fastq"):        #condition for fastq files
    for i in range(1,len(xread),4):
        fast = fast + xread[i].strip('\n')

rev_comp(x)
```

And what I wind up with is

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

when I try to run the script using a .fastq file. What exactly is going wrong here? I expect the script to write Rev_comp.fasta, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not a filehandle, just a file name. You need to do

```
with open(x) as xhandle:
    xread = xhandle.readlines()
```

The overall logic might be better if you don't read all lines into memory. Also, the `.gz` case ends up in vaguely undefined territory; do you need to set `x` to the name of the unzipped data at the end of the `gz` handling, or perhaps put the code after it into an `else:` branch?

Comment: Tangentially related meta discussion on similar answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322722/people-vote-reputation-myth-or-reality/322728#322728

Answer (score 1):

x is the input from the user, which is a string. You need to `open` a file to be able to call `readlines` on it.

According to your existing code:

```
x = input("Enter filename (with extension) of the DNA sequence: ") # x stores a string

file_x = open(x, 'r')  # You must open a file ...

xread = file_x.readlines()  # and call readlines on the file instance.

# Although it is not explicitly necessary, remember to close the file when you'done, is good practice.
file_x.close()
```

or use the [file as a context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html)

```
with open(x) as file_x:
    xread = file_x.readlines()
```

Comment: You need to use `with` or explicitly close the file when you're done.

Comment: Please fix the typo in `file_X`, which should be `file_x`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks I update my answer according, it is a good practice, but you don't need to explicitly close the file, GC will close it for you if there when the reference count for the object reach 0, and no exceptions (this is the part for good practice).

Comment: In the general case, you can't be sure that your code doesn't get copy-pasted into a loop where you do run out of file handles eventually, completely unnecessarily. Doing the right thing instead is completely trivial here.

Comment: @tripleee Copy/paste is indeed a bad practice. If you do, you have to have understanding of what your copying and implications, and, if that the case (you know what you're copying), you'll be aware you've to close the file.